# On clicking the SSRS Tablix Show another Report with that raw data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have SSRS report with Five raws of data .
For example Five employee details with employee id,name,salary etc.

When i am clicking in one of the raw i want the corresoponding raw data to be displayed in another report.

I have tried like passing the employee id and in the second report i have changed the query to where empid=@empid..
so in the second report will display only the raw with that empid.

But i dont want to do like this..
Please give any ideas..

Comment: Any reason not to create additional Sub report parameters for the other columns besides empid that you have already created as a sub report parameter.

Comment: no any specific reason because empid is enough to get the specified raw..

Comment: i think you are searching something like this: go through with this link http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2014/08/ssrs-drill-through-example.html